# how to authenticate the credentials of the page to another page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two solutions ( www.mypages.com/siteA and www.mypages.com/siteB), but the SiteB page will only be accessed if the SiteA is authenticated . How do I send SiteA to SiteB authentication? Could show me an example? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be implemented with Single Sign On (SSO) mechanism like the one [here](http://arunendapally.com/post/implementation-of-single-sign-on-(sso)-in-asp.net-mvc)...

Comment: Thanks for help . I can create SSO in different solutions, for example sso in the solution , the WebApp1 in another solution and webApp2 of another solution?

Comment: Yes, better keep the app solutions separate. This way you can add more in future.